# session storage path setting doesn't exist

Tags: python, django

I am trying to run a django project and the following error is displayed: 'The session storage path '/home/billy/myapps/my_server/../my_server/sessions' doesn't exist. Please set your SESSION_FILE_PATH setting to an existing directory in which Django can store session data.'
I have tried googling out whats the problem but u have not found a specific answer to my problem. Any assistance is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message looks pretty clear to me. **Solution 0**:

1. Create the directory `/home/billy/myapps/my_server/sessions`
2. Figure what user runs Django, ie. with `ps aux` command,
3. Give [rwx permissions](http://blog.yourlabs.org/post/19240900759/survive-linux-nix-permissions) to that user on that directory.

**Solution 1**: use [database backed sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#using-database-backed-sessions) - in that case remove `settings.SESSION_ENGINE` to restore the default.

Answer (score 0):

The path '/home/billy/myapps//my_server/sessions' must exist. And process of your application server must have corresponding rights to work with it.